# Generating forms dynamically from json data

Tags: forms, 9

I have a large set of JSON data which I need to process somehow into forms for users to interact with, fill in data and submit.

However, there are far too many to create all the forms by hand and I wonder if anyone can recommend a module/package which I can use to create such large number of forms dynamically.

Below is a very small sample section of json data, each section in the json needs to be processed into a unique step of a multipage form:

```
{
    "one":{
        "Label": "Please provide your age and date-of-birth",
        "fields": [
            "Age",
            "DOB"        
        ]
    },
    "two":{
        "Label": "Please provide your address",
        "fields": [
            "Address"        
        ]
    },
    "three":{
        "Label": "Please provide your 6 target areas",
        "fields": [
            "Area 1",
            "Area 2",
            "Area 3",
            "Area 4",
            "Area 5",
            "Area 6"
        ]
    }
}
```

As the data above shows, each of the forms have different number of fields. The **labels** will be textfield lables and the **fields** will be textfields.

Can anyone offer some suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: Although sometimes an answer contains a module recommendation, asking for that is against the forum rules: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks to find, recommend, or suggest hosting providers, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is going to be tough, unfortunately.

The [Feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) has good JSON support, so that's a way to get the data in.  The problem is: what will you import to?  [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) would seem to be an obvious choice, but [Feeds only has support for importing webform submissions, not the actual forms themselves.](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2998203)

### Building it yourself

I have built forms using data stored on entities with the [JSON Field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/json_field).

The basic approach is:

- Create a custom content type or custom entity type (**Custom Form Type**).
- Add a JSON field (**My JSON Form**) to **Custom Form Type**.
- Import the JSON data to create the forms of **Custom Form Type** (using Feeds?).
- Add a custom formatter (extending FormatterBase) to view the form field. (Optional. Users may not need to view the form field, and admins may be OK viewing raw JSON.)
- Add a custom widget (extending StringTextareaWidget if you are using a JSON field) to add the drupal form fields.

How can users submit this form?

One way to do it:

- Add a custom content type or custom entity type (**Custom Form Submission**).
- Add a JSON field (**My JSON Submission**) to **Custom Form Submission**.
- Add an entity reference field to type **Custom Form Type**.
- Add logic to **Custom Form Type** that automatically creates a **Custom Form Submission** when submitted.

What about JSON validation?  I built a validator with [Opis JSON Schema](https://opis.io/json-schema/) and then run a check against my custom schema.

### Reference

It might also be helpful to look at the [JSON Field Utils](https://www.drupal.org/project/jfu) module, which seems to be trying to re-implement paragraphs with JSON.  This is not what you asked for, but it may give you ideas about how to code your own module.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your initial comments about Feeds and Webforms is exactly what I explored earlier. I don't mind creating a custom module to achieve the desired results so your "Build it yourself" suggestion is very interesting - can you offer a bit more details on your form builds? I'm especially interested in knowing if in your build the submitted data was stored in the database via form fields ?

Comment: @sisko Updated.

Comment: Appreciated Patrick. I will begin looking into all your recommendations. Thanks.

Comment: I have to give you credit and say thanks. I followed your approach and I am successfully able to use the Drupal Form API to auto generate forms dynamically from my imported JSON.

Comment: @sisko Happy to help!

Comment: Hi Sisko, I exactly need this functionality. Are you willing to share code?